# how can I clean my code content once bs4 scrapes the code snippet?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, feedparser

I am trying to scrape all the data content inside code , but however my code looks like kinda weirdy on `code_snippet = soup.find('code')` since it display different data as the following:

```
<code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">backend/src</code>
None
hh2019/09/22/dragonteaser19-rms/
<code>What do?
        list [p]ending requests
        list [f]inished requests
        [v]iew result of request
        [a]dd new request
        [q]uit
Choice? [pfvaq]
</code>
None
hh2019/01/02/exploiting-math-expm1-v8/
<code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">nc 35.246.172.142 1</code>
None
hh2018/12/23/xmas18-white-rabbit/
<code class="MathJax_Preview">n</code>
None
hh2018/12/02/pwn2win18-tpm20/
<code>Welcome to my trusted platform. Tell me what do you want:
hh2018/05/21/rctf18-stringer/
<code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">calloc</code>
None
```

However, printing the `soup = BeautifulSoup(content['value'], "html.parser")` it returns the right data `pre > code` where it interest me only the content inside these tags , and looks like this

```
<h3 id="overview">Overview</h3>
<p>The challenge shipped with several cave templates.
A user can build a cave from an existing template and populate it with treasures in random positions.
For caves created by the gamebot, the treasures are flags.
Any user can visit a cave by providing a program written in a custom programming language.
The program has to navigate around the cave.
If it terminates on a treasure, the treasure’s contents will be printed.</p>
<p>I was drawn to this challenge because the custom programming language is compiled to machine code using LLVM, and then executed.
It seemed like a fun place to look for bugs.</p>
<p>The challenge ships the backend’s source code in <code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">backend/src</code>, some program samples in <code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">backend/samples</code>, and the prebuilt binaries in <code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">backend/build</code>.
The <code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">backend/build/SaarlangCompiler</code> executable is a standalone compiler for the language.
It’s useful for testing, but it is not used in the challenge.
The actual server is <code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">backend/build/SchlossbergCaveServer</code>.
It binds to the local port 9081, and it is exposed to other teams through a nginx reverse proxy on port 9080.
I will use port 9081 in examples and exploits so that they can be tested locally without nginx.</p>
<h3 id="api-interactions">API interactions</h3>
<p>The APIs are defined in <code class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge">backend/src/api.cpp</code>.
We will take a look at some typical API interactions.
I will prettify JSON responses for your convenience.</p>
<p>First, we need to register a user:</p>
<div class="language-plaintext highlighter-rouge"><div class="highlight"><pre class="highlight"><code>$ curl -c cookies -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
       -d '{"username": "abiondo", "password": "secret"}'     \
       http://localhost:9081/api/users/register
{
    "username": "abiondo"
}
</code></pre></div></div>
```

I want to scrape all `<pre *><code>` and clean it with `code_snippet.get_text()`, but I am not sure, what I am missing on this, however, I am using `asyncio + feedparser + bs4` for a scraper, but at some point, it's giving me the wrong data on this.

```
for entrie in entries:
    print(entrie['link'])
    for content in entrie['content']:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content['value'], "html.parser")
        code_snippet = soup.find('code')
        print(soup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `pre > code`. That will select all `<code>` directly under `<pre>`:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://abiondo.me/2020/03/22/saarctf20-schlossberg/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for code in soup.select('pre > code'):
    print(code.get_text())
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
$ curl -c cookies -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
       -d '{"username": "abiondo", "password": "secret"}'     \
       http://localhost:9081/api/users/register
{
    "username": "abiondo"
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ curl -b cookies -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
       -d '{"name": "MyFancyCave", "template": 1}'            \
       http://localhost:9081/api/caves/rent
{
    "created": 1584867401,
    "id": "1584867401_1345632849",
    "name": "MyFancyCave",
    "owner": "abiondo",
    "template_id": 1,
    "treasure_count": 0,
    "treasures": []
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ curl -b cookies -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
       -d '{"cave_id": "1584867401_1345632849", "names": [    \
                "SAAR{OneFancyFlagOneFancyFlag00000000}",     \
                "SAAR{TwoFancyFlagsTwoFancyFlags000000}"]}'   \
       http://localhost:9081/api/caves/hide-treasures
{
    "created": 1584867401,
    "id": "1584867401_1345632849",
    "name": "MyFancyCave",
    "owner": "abiondo",
    "template_id": 1,
    "treasure_count": 2,
    "treasures": [
        {
            "name": "SAAR{OneFancyFlagOneFancyFlag00000000}",
            "x": 645,
            "y": 97
        },
        {
            "name": "SAAR{TwoFancyFlagsTwoFancyFlags000000}",
            "x": 505,
            "y": 14
        }
    ]
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
soup.findAll("code",{"class":"language-plaintext"}.text
```